# Encryption/Decryption using X509 certificate in biztalk custome pipeline component

Tags: biztalk, pipeline, encryption-asymmetric

I need to use X509 certificate in the BizTalk Custom Pipeline component to Encrypt/Sign the message and to Decrypt/Verify signature, please let me know some good samples/artcile/blogs etc which explains how to acheive this.

RSA needs to be the encrypton algoritham.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of encryption are you looking for? Are you looking for raw RSA encryption, or any specific message format?

Out of the box, BizTalk only supports S/MIME encryption using the SMIME encoder/decoder component; it might be useful depending on exactly your format is.

As for how to create a custom pipeline component from scratch to do it, I recommend first starting with the [Pipeline Component Wizard](http://www.codeplex.com/btsplcw). It will take care of most of the boilerplate code.

I do have a [sample](http://winterdom.com/2006/04/symmetricencryptiondecryptionpipelinecomponents) on writing custom encryption pipeline components, though my specific sample uses symmetric encryption and not RSA (but should give you a clue as to how to implement this). The code for these components can be found [here](http://github.com/tomasr/cryptopipeline).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post we just uploaded can be of help: http://www.leandrodg.com.ar/blog/2010/03/encryption-and-decryption-with-x-509-certificates/